# Obtener la condición de un bucle

Tags: javascript, while, bucle-for, asincronismo

Si tengo un bucle:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) { 
ended = 5 - i === 1 && OperationSymbol.trim() === "i<5" true : false;
}
```

Que pretendo ? Primero obtener el condicional que se realiza en el for,

en este caso la condición es `i < 5` , mientras `i` sea **menor** que `5`, para qué?

Luego con esto, crearé una variable ,el nombre de esta será irrelevante,
lo que hará esta función es comprobar si el for ha acabado, y cómo ? ya que la condición es `i < 5`, cuando `i` **sea igual** a `4`, será el último ciclo, por ende `5` `- i (4)` **seria igual** a `1`.

El problema de esto, es:

> ¿Cómo obtengo la condición de un ciclo ?

, ya sea `for` o `while`

> ¿La variable sería ASIGNADA dentro de un ciclo for, pero cómo podría
>   saber si realmente está en un ciclo for?

, osea **cómo sé donde está** una *variable x* ?

Con esto, desde cualquier función podra hacer algo cómo:

```
if (cicloX.ended()) // console.log("El ciclo finalizó, los datos están listos")
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitarías sería envolver el bucle dentro de una promesa, y teniendo una referencia a esa promesa en otra parte del código, usar el método `then` de la promesa para ejecutar otra acción.

Cambié un poco tu ejemplo para que el bucle fuera asíncrono, pero dentro de la promesa puedes meter un `while` o `for` como te acomode:

```js
var ti,
    contador=0,
    acumulador=[];
    promesa = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        ti = window.setInterval(function() {

           console.log('ciclo ',contador);
           
           acumulador.push(contador);
           if(acumulador.length>=5) {
            window.clearInterval(ti);
            resolve(acumulador);
           }
           contador++;

        },500);
});

promesa.then(function(resultado) {
 
  console.log('acumulador terminó y tiene valores', acumulador);

});
```

Probablemente para el caso de uso que estás pensando, te sería más util ocupar alguna especie de `deferred` que puedes resolver manualmente sin envolver tu bucle en un constructor de promesa.

```js
function Deferred() {
  var resolve, reject;
  var promise = new Promise(function() {
      resolve = arguments[0];
      reject = arguments[1];
  });
  return {
      resolve: resolve,
      reject: reject,
      promise: promise
  };
}

var ti,
    contador=0,
    acumuladorListener= new Deferred();
    
acumuladorListener.promise.then(function(resultado) {
  console.log('acumulador terminó y tiene valores', acumulador);
});    
    
var acumulador=[];
    ti = window.setInterval(function() {
      console.log('ciclo ',contador);
      acumulador.push(contador);
      if(acumulador.length>=5) {
        window.clearInterval(ti);
        acumuladorListener.resolve(acumulador);
      }
      contador++;
    },500);
```